# Añadir a un excel en la ultima fila

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, openpyxl

Buenas tardes a todos!!

Me gustaría, en este fragmento de código que traigo, añadir a una columna en concreto, que conozco a priori, un valor en la celda siguiente de la última rellena, pero me da error, entiendo que no estoy declarando bien el momento de escribir. ¿Alguien me podría decir como se haría?

Muchas gracias por adelantado!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox,filedialog,ttk,PhotoImage #libreria IMPRESCINDIBLE para meter ventanas emergentes
from PIL import Image,ImageTk,ImageDraw #libreria que necesito para imagenes
import openpyxl

#Definición de variables globales

raiz=Tk()

prueba=StringVar()

libro = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/jose.velazquez/Downloads/Prueba.xlsx')
hoja = libro['Datos']
max_fila = hoja.max_row
print(max_fila)

ancho_ventana = 500 #ancho de la ventana
alto_ventana = 250 #alto de la ventana


def inserta_proyecto(num,hoja):
    global max_fila
    a=max_fila+1
    añadir=hoja[a][4]
    añadir.value=num


x_ventana = raiz.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - ancho_ventana // 2 #posición del ancho de la ventana
y_ventana = raiz.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - alto_ventana // 2 #posición del alto de la ventana

posicion = str(ancho_ventana) + "x" + str(alto_ventana) + "+" + str(x_ventana) + "+" + str(y_ventana) #determinación de la posición de la pantalla

prueba.set("")

pregunta=Label(raiz, text="Inserta un nuevo proyecto")
pregunta.place(x=50,y=75)
cuadro=Entry(raiz,textvariable=prueba)
cuadro.place(x=215,y=75)
boton=Button(raiz,text="Actualizar",command=lambda: inserta_proyecto(cuadro.get(),hoja))
boton.place(x=200,y=120)



raiz.geometry(posicion)
raiz.resizable(0,0)



raiz.mainloop()
```

El error que me sale es el siguiente, por si os aporta información:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jose.velazquez\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jose.velazquez\Desktop\Proyecto Programa2\untitled0.py", line 39, in <lambda>
    boton=Button(raiz,text="Actualizar",command=lambda: inserta_proyecto(cuadro.get(),hoja))
  File "C:\Users\jose.velazquez\Desktop\Proyecto Programa2\untitled0.py", line 24, in inserta_proyecto
    añadir=hoja[a][4]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado!!

Comment: Por lo que veo, hoja[a] va a devolver una tupla. El item 4 (es decir, la quinta columna) no existe al parecer (el error que ves ocurre cuando quieres acceder a una parte de una sequencia que va mas allá del largo de esta). Cual es la columna que quieres afectar?

Comment: Buenas! Yo quiero afectar a la columna que sea necesario, había puesto 4 por escribir una. Simplemente quiero colocarlo en la última fila ocupada y en una columna cualquiera.

Comment: Probaste con un numero de columna por debajo de la ultima columna donde hay contenido?

Comment: si, y se añadía sin problemas

Comment: Entonces, si entiendo bien. Quieres escribir contenido en una columna y fila, incluso si la columna elegida supera a la ultima con valores y lo mismo con la fila?

Comment: Claro, quiero escribir en, una columna concreta, en la fila siguiente a la última rellena, para seguir añadiendo datos a una table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es el método [append](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append) del objeto worksheet.

Cito la documentación:

> ###### append(iterable)
>
> Appends a group of values at the bottom of the
> current sheet.
>
> - If it’s a list: all values are added in order, starting from the first column
> - If it’s a dict: values are assigned to the columns indicated by the keys (numbers or letters)
>
> Parameters:   iterable(list|tuple|range|generator or dict) – list, range or generator, or
> dict containing values to append

Que traducido por mi y el traductor de google es:

> ###### append(iterable)
>
> Agrega un grupo de valores en la parte inferior de la hoja actual.
>
> - Si es una lista: todos los valores se agregan en orden, comenzando desde la primera columna
> - Si es un diccionario: se asignan valores a las columnas indicadas por las claves (números o letras)
>
> Parametros:   iterable(list|tuple|range|generator or dict) – lista, rango o generador, o
> diccionario conteniendo los valores a agregar

Esto significa que append puede agregar un valor abajo de todo en columnas especificas (comprobé que incluso funciona si la columna supera la ultima columna por valores) si se le pasa un diccionario de argumento.

El código quedaría así:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox,filedialog,ttk,PhotoImage #libreria IMPRESCINDIBLE para meter ventanas emergentes
from PIL import Image,ImageTk,ImageDraw #libreria que necesito para imagenes
import openpyxl

#Definición de variables globales

raiz=Tk()

prueba=StringVar()

libro = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/jose.velazquez/Downloads/Prueba.xlsx')
hoja = libro['Datos']

ancho_ventana = 500 #ancho de la ventana
alto_ventana = 250 #alto de la ventana


def inserta_proyecto(num,hoja):
    hoja.append({"E":num})    

x_ventana = raiz.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - ancho_ventana // 2 #posición del ancho de la ventana
y_ventana = raiz.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - alto_ventana // 2 #posición del alto de la ventana

posicion = str(ancho_ventana) + "x" + str(alto_ventana) + "+" + str(x_ventana) + "+" + str(y_ventana) #determinación de la posición de la pantalla

prueba.set("")

pregunta=Label(raiz, text="Inserta un nuevo proyecto")
pregunta.place(x=50,y=75)
cuadro=Entry(raiz,textvariable=prueba)
cuadro.place(x=215,y=75)
boton=Button(raiz,text="Actualizar",command=lambda: inserta_proyecto(cuadro.get(),hoja))
boton.place(x=200,y=120)



raiz.geometry(posicion)
raiz.resizable(0,0)



raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por su respuesta!!! Me ha ayudado a mejorar mi código! Un saludo enorme!

Comment: De nada Joanto c: